# Microsoft Visual Studio 2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

There's a problem in the following code when "=" is pressed more than once, it doesn't repeat the previous input but add's the input from Answer box to typed box.. 
what i am trying to achieve here is that when "=" is pressed second or third and so forth, the "=" would repeat the previous function without crashing or just shifting up numbers..

```
Public Class Form1

    'Global variable to check if equals has been pressed
    Dim is_equals_pressed As Boolean = False
    Dim operator_count As Integer = 0
    Dim allowed_input As Boolean = False

    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''Dim num3 As Double = 0.0'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

    Private Sub btnPlus_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnPlus.Click
        operator_count += 1
        allowed_input = Check_Values()
        If allowed_input <> False Then
            If txtAnswer.Text = "" Then
                If Check_Values() = False Then
                    txtAnswer.Focus()
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            End If
            If is_equals_pressed = True Then
                txtTyped.Text = txtAnswer.Text & "+"
                txtAnswer.Text = ""    'clear the text box
                is_equals_pressed = False
            Else
                txtTyped.Text += txtAnswer.Text & "+"
                txtAnswer.Text = ""    'clear the text box
                txtAnswer.Focus()
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

---

---

```
        If is_equals_pressed = True Then
                txtTyped.Text = txtAnswer.Text & "/"
                txtAnswer.Text = ""    'clear the text box
                is_equals_pressed = False
            Else
                txtTyped.Text += txtAnswer.Text & "/"
                txtAnswer.Text = ""    'clear the text box
                txtAnswer.Focus()
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnEquals_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnEquals.Click
        Dim equation As String
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''Dim i As Integer = 0'''''''''''''''''

        '''''''''''''''Deal with equals the previous operation''''''''''''''''''''
        ''''''''''''''''If operator_count = 0 Then'''''''''''''''
        ''''''''''''''''If equation.Contains("+") Then'''''''''''''''
        ''''''''''''''''equation.Replace(equation(3), num3)'''''''''''''''
        ''''''''''''''''End If'''''''''''''''
        ''''''''''''''''End If'''''''''''''''

        operator_count = 0
        'Cos, Sin, Tan
        Dim num1 As String
        'End
        Dim i As Integer = 1
        txtTyped.Text += txtAnswer.Text
        'Capture value for Cos, Sin, Tan calculation
        num1 = txtAnswer.Text
        'End
        txtAnswer.Text = ("") 'Clear the text box
        equation = txtTyped.Text
        'Check if equals has been pressed
        is_equals_pressed = True
        'Check for +, -, =, / simbol in string
        For i = 1 To equation.Length - 1
            If equation(i) = "+" Then
                addNumbers(equation)
            ElseIf equation(i) = "-" Then
                subtrtactNumbers(equation)
            ElseIf equation(i) = "*" Then
                multiplyNumbers(equation)
            ElseIf equation(i) = "/" Then
                divideNumbers(equation)
            ElseIf equation(i) = "^" Then
                exponentNumber(equation)
            ElseIf equation(i) = "%" Then
                modulusNumbers(equation)
            ElseIf equation.Contains("1/") Then
                inverseNumbers(equation)
                'We do this calculation in btnCos_Click
            ElseIf equation.Contains("Cos") Then
            ElseIf equation.Contains("Sin") Then
            ElseIf equation.Contains("Tan") Then
            End If
        Next
        txtAnswer.Select(txtAnswer.Text.Length, 0)
    End Sub

    Public Sub addNumbers(ByVal equation As String)
        Dim num1, num2 As String
        Dim answer As Double
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        num1 = ""
        num2 = ""
        'Get the first number
        While equation(i) <> "+"
            num1 += equation(i)
            i += 1
        End While
        'Get the second number 
        i += 1
        While equation(i) <> ""
            num2 += equation(i)
            i += 1
            If i = equation.Length Then
                Exit While
            End If
        End While
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''num3 = num2''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        answer = Convert.ToDouble(num1) + Convert.ToDouble(num2)
        txtAnswer.Text = answer
    End Sub
    'would work but not for the minus 

    Private Function Check_Values() As Boolean
        'Dim allowed As Boolean = True
        'Dim equation As String
        'equation = txtTyped.Text
        'If txtTyped.Text = "" Then
        'allowed = False
        'End If
        'If equation(0) = "-" Then
        'allowed = True
        'End If
        'Check_Values = allowed
        If operator_count > 1 Then
            allowed_input = False
        Else
            allowed_input = True
        End If
        Check_Values = allowed_input
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Please make the title of your question more descriptive of your actual problem.  Your current title doesn't give any useful information.

Comment: Also you can add some background... It took some times to understand you were actually trying to build a calculator...

Comment: This code won't compile - When you have a look at my edit to your code, you'll see that you have an `End Sub` above the break, and a bit further down, another `End Sub`. There should either be a matching `Private sub btnMinus_Click....`  declaration somewhere just below the break and above the second `End Sub`.